# C# Entity Framework - Entity only relating to one entry at a time

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

So I am have difficulty understanding why `CompaniesAccepted` is only allowing one Company to be related at a time.

So for example if I have 2 entries of File in my Database. The company then accepts one of these files and gets added to CompaniesAccepted list. If I try to add this same company to the other File entry, the Company will be removed from the CompaniesAccepted list from the first file and added to the list of the new one which doesn't make sense to me as I wish to have the Company in both of those lists.

```
public class File
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Company> CompaniesAccepted { get; set; }

    public bool isDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

Company Entity

```
public class Company
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ParentCompany { get; set; }

    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public string LegalName { get; set; }

    public string DUNS { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Company CustomerCompany { get; set; }

    public bool isActivated { get; set; }

    public bool isDeleted { get; set; }

}
```

Code used to add the relationship.

```
        if(accepted)
        {
            var company = file.CompaniesAccepted.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == account.Company.Id);
            if(company == null)
            {
                file.CompaniesAccepted.Add(account.Company);
            }
        } else
        {
            file.CompaniesAccepted.Remove(account.Company);
        }
        Db.SaveChanges();
```

Any suggestions? If I haven't provided enough code, please do ask.

Comment: In a nutshell, you've set up a 1 to many relationship: 1 company, many files. The company table will have a single foreign key for the file `Id`. If you include your `Company` class in your question, it should be easy enough to identify that foreign key field.

Comment: If you truly need a many to many relationship (each file can have multiple companies, and each company can have multiple files), you need a join table to be able to do that. There are EF many-to-many tutorials that can help with that, e.g. https://entityframework.net/many-to-many-relationship

Comment: @David784 I've included the Company class.

Comment: You're definitely creating a one-to-many relationship. See [here](https://entityframework.net/one-to-many-relationship#add-collection-navigation-property). This relationship means each Company can only have one associated File, and each File can have multiple associated Companies. See previous comment, if you need a many-to-many relationship.